# Install pytorch python

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Пытался установить PyTorch через cmd и PyCharm - выдаёт ошибку, не знаю, что делать.

C оф.сайта копировал команду установки не проходит.

[image: Ошибка Установки]

Вот сама ошибка 
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/67/f403d4ae6e9cd74b546ee88cccdb29b8415a9c1b3d80aebeb20c9ea91d96/pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch: started
    Running setup.py install for pytorch: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command D:\PythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3eqbg30v\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\PythonProject1\venv\include\site\python3.7\pytorch:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\setup.py", line 11, in 
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "D:\PythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-3eqbg30v\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers D:\PythonProject1\venv\include\site\python3.7\pytorch" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pytorch\

Comment: Скопируйте и добавьте в вопрос весь текст ошибки, там где Command output, а скриншот можете для красоты оставить. Т.к. на нем ничего не понятно, а вся суть проблемы в тексте ошибки ниже и ее не видно :)

Comment: Вставил выше ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для установки стабильной версии PyTorch для Windows, для Python версии 3.7, согласно [официальной документации](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) требуется набрать следующую команду:

```
pip3 install torch===1.3.0 torchvision===0.4.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Не работает в этом то и дело  , вот что выдаёт :Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.3.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch===1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install pytorch #если Python 3.+.+
```

Comment: pip3 это для запуска только для python3 и нужно оно если в системе стоит python2 и python3 одновременно, а мы хотим только для python3 поставить. А автора ведь установка через IDE идет, а та знает папку текущего в проекте питона и где у него pip находится, поэтому вам ответ не поможет :)